# How to use postgresql service file in pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

My service file is working well in PgAdmin3 and in QGIS.
I'm trying to use the same service file in PgAdmin4. But no luck, I still have the same message:

> Unable to connect to server: definition of service "XXXX" not found

My service is located in:

```
/etc/postgresql-common/pg_service.conf
```

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and I used this webpage to install PgAdmin4: https://askubuntu.com/a/831263/363564

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the latest version of pgAdmin4, Many features are implemented now,

Specifically, the one you asked for https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3140